# Removing the end of a filename in python

Tags: python, string, file

I need to remove the end off a filename below:

```
Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175
```

So anything after CSV needs to be removed so i have a file named:

```
Testfile_20190226114536.CSV
```

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: Do you know anything about the file names ahead of time, other than that the substring `.CSV.` occurs somewhere in the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
s = 'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175'
suffix = '.CSV'

s[:s.rindex(suffix) + len(suffix)]
=> 'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV'
```

Comment: I would use `.CSV` and not `CSV` :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `file_name = "Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175"`

```
file_name = file_name.split('.CSV')[0] + '.CSV'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
result = re.sub('(?<=\.CSV)[\w\W]+', '', 'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175')
```

Output:

```
'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is this

All of your files have this "CSV" in the middle?

You can try split and join your name like this:

```
name = "Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175"
print ".".join(name.split(".")[0:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps to see what's going on

```
>>> filename = 'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175'

# split the string into a list at '.'
>>> l = filename.split('.')

>>> print(l)
['Testfile_20190226114536', 'CSV', '986466', '1551204043175']

# index the list to get all the elements before and including 'CSV'
>>> filtered_list = l[0:l.index('CSV')+1]

>>> print(filtered_list)
['Testfile_20190226114536', 'CSV']

# join together the elements of the list with '.'
>>> out_string = '.'.join(filtered_list)
>>> print(out_string)

Testfile_20190226114536.CSV
```

Here's a full function:

```
def filter_filename(filename):
    l = filename.split('.')
    filtered_list = l[0:l.index('CSV')+1]
    out_string = '.'.join(filtered_list)
    return out_string

>>> filter_filename('Testfile_20190226114536.CSV.986466.1551204043175')
'Testfile_20190226114536.CSV'
```